# Control flux in python if/elif continue

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a `if`/`elif` statement in Python, but I want to execute both commands next. I want to show `AD0` and `AD1` every second, but the code is just showing `AD1` (Not entering on `elif`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import serial
from time import sleep
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600, timeout=0)

while True:
    arquivo = open('temperatura.txt','r')
    conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    data = ser.read(9999)
    if len(data) > 0:
        if 'AD0'in data:
            temp = data[4:7]
            #print 'Got:', data
            #string = str('A temperatura é',temp,'ºC')             
            conteudo.append(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
            conteudo.append(' ')
            conteudo.append('[AD0]A temperatura é')
            conteudo.append(temp)
            conteudo.append('ºC')           
            print '[AD0]A temperatura é',temp,'ºC'
            #print string 
            conteudo.append('\n')
            arquivo = openarquivo = open('temperatura.txt','w')
            arquivo.writelines(conteudo)
            continue

        elif 'AD1'in data:
            temp = data[4:7]
            #print 'Got:', data
            #string = str('A temperatura é',temp,'ºC')             
            conteudo.append(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
            conteudo.append(' ')
            conteudo.append('[AD1]A temperatura é')
            conteudo.append(temp)
            conteudo.append('ºC')           
            print '[AD1]A temperatura é',temp,'ºC'
            #print string 
            conteudo.append('\n')
            arquivo = openarquivo = open('temperatura.txt','w')
            arquivo.writelines(conteudo)   

    sleep(1)
    #print 'not blocked'
    arquivo.close()

ser.close()
```

Comment: Try keeping just the if instead of else

Comment: Your question is confusing. The `elif` block would only execute if `AD1` is present, but you state that `AD1` is showing but the `elif` is *not* executed?

Comment: I've executing both, but now, the values are the same (the values is different).

Answer (score 0):

Python will pick the *first* matching condition out of a series of `if..elif..` tests, and will execute just that *one* block of code.

If your two tests should be *independent* and both should be considered, replace the `elif` block with a separate `if` statement:

```
if 'AD0'in data:
    # ...

if 'AD1'in data:
    # ...
```

Now both conditions will be tested independently and if both match, both will be executed.

Comment: I've do that, but now is showing the same value in AD0 and AD1 (the values are different)

if len(data) > 0:
        if 'AD0'in data:
            temp = data[4:7]
            print '[AD1]A temperatura é',temp2,'ºC'
     
  
               
        if 'AD1'in data:
            temp2 = data[4:7]
         
            print '[AD1]A temperatura é',temp2,'ºC'

Comment: @FelipeFerreiraMendes: you'll need to refine your parsing, or load less data at a time from your serial port. I can't help with that part; you'd have to ask a new question that includes the output of `print(repr(data))` so that people can actually see what you are trying to parse. Right now you are assuming that `data[4:7]` is always the right piece in the data you loaded.